# How to retrieve ssm parameter value using serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have a AWS SSM parameter which is `stringlist` type and it contains 3 subnet ids. I want to get the first subnet id and below code I am using

```
SubnetId: !Select [0, !Split [",", "${ssm:/subnet-ids}"]]
```

This is giving below error:

> Template error: every Fn::Split object requires two parameters, (1) a
> string delimiter and (2) a string to be split or a function that
> returns a string to be split.

How can I use intrinsic function to fetch the value of the string list parameter?

Comment: Did you try `${ssm(raw):/subnet-ids}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent releases of Serverless Framework handles this automatically by default. No need to use the `!Split` intrinsic function anymore. Read more here: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#resolve-stringlist-as-array-of-strings